# CMake/CPack command for InstallDirRegKey

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

In an NSIS script file, it is possible to set the following, to use a registry entry as the install directory:

```
InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\Test" "RegEntry"
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to set this command from a cmake file, so that the NSIS script is automatically generated. Much in the same way the directory of an install can be set like:

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "testDir")
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following exactly what you're trying to do, but if you just want a custom command in the NSIS file, you can do this:

```
list(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS " 
                InstallDirRegKey HKCU \"Software\\Test\" \"RegEntry\"
               ")
```

Be careful of the backslashes, needed to escape the double quote and the literal backslash.  I think you might need 4 backslashes instead of 2 for the literal backslash, but try it and see.  Check the resulting NSIS file, and add more backslashes as necessary.

**EDIT:**

There's another, much more complete way to customize the NSIS install script. According to this: http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackNSISAdvancedTips you can copy NSIS.template.in (from your CMake installation) into your source tree (in a directory that's on your CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) and modify it.

Comment: I would like the command to be run at the beginning of the NSIS file (outside of a section if possible); so that it is used as a default install location.

Comment: According to this: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackNSISAdvancedTips you can copy NSIS.template.in into your source tree (in a directory that's on your CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) and modify it.  That might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS " 
                 InstallDirRegKey HKCU \"Software\\Test\" \"RegEntry\"
                ")
```

translates on my machine to

```
InstallDirRegKey HKCU ;Software\Test" "RegEntry;`
```

Try rather

```
 list(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS " 
                InstallDirRegKey HKCU 'Software\\\\Test' 'RegEntry'
                ")
```